# Gradient of Square of Quadratic Inner-Product

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f(x) :=&   {\langle}x,Ax{\rangle}^2\\
=& x^{T}Axx^{T} Ax\\
& x \in \mathbb{R}^n,\\
& A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, \;A = A^T.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

The 2nd answer is the generalization + example code to validate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the result is $\nabla f(x) = 4\langle x, Ax\rangle Ax$.

When in doubt, you can just write out the sums explicitly. We have $$\langle x,Ax\rangle =\sum_{i=1}^n x_i(Ax)_i = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}x_j = \sum_{i,j=1}^nA_{ij}x_ix_j$$

Therefore
\begin{align}
\partial_kf(x) &= \partial_k \left(\sum_{i,j=1}^nA_{ij}x_ix_j\right)^2 \\
&= 2\left(\sum_{i,j=1}^nA_{ij}x_ix_j\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^nA_{ik}x_i + \sum_{j=1}^nA_{kj}x_j\right)\\
&= 2\langle x,Ax\rangle\left(\sum_{i=1}^nA_{ki}x_i + \sum_{j=1}^nA_{kj}x_j\right)\\
&= 4\langle x,Ax\rangle\left(\sum_{j=1}^nA_{kj}x_j\right)\\
&= 4\langle x,Ax\rangle(Ax)_k
\end{align}

so $$\nabla f(x) = \begin{bmatrix} \partial_1 f(x) \\ \vdots \\ \partial_n f(x)\end{bmatrix} = 4\langle x,Ax\rangle\begin{bmatrix} (Ax)_1 \\ \vdots \\ (Ax)_n\end{bmatrix} = 4\langle x,Ax\rangle Ax$$

---

For the Hessian, notice that
$$\partial_l\big[\langle x,Ax\rangle\big] = (Ak)_l$$
$$\partial_l \big[(Ax)_k\big] = \partial_l\left(\sum_{j=1}^n A_{kj}x_j\right) = A_{kl}$$
We have
\begin{align}
\partial_l\partial_k f(x) &= \partial_l\big[4\langle x,Ax\rangle (Ax)_k\big]\\
&= 4\Big[\partial_l\big[\langle x,Ax\rangle\big](Ax)_k + \langle x,Ax\rangle  \partial_l \big[(Ax)_k\big]\Big]\\
&= 4\Big[(Ax)_l(Ax)_k + \langle x,Ax\rangle  A_{kl}\Big]\\
\end{align}

so the Hessian is given by
$$H(x) = \Big[\partial_l\partial_k f(x)\Big]_{1\le l,k\le n} = 4\Big[(Ax)_l(Ax)_k\Big]_{1\le l,k\le n} + 4\langle x,Ax\rangle\Big[  A_{kl}\Big]_{1\le l,k\le n} = 4 A \otimes A + 4\langle x,Ax\rangle A$$

Comment: Thanks pal. I really need to go to bed, but can we also try the Hessian?

Comment: @Robin I have added the Hessian, have a look.

Comment: @mechanodriod, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the generalization and the matlab script that you can see it is correct.
Interestingly, it is nothing but chain-rule, we take outer-derivative, and the inner-derivative, and done.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f(x) :=&   {\langle}X,AX{\rangle}_F^2\\
=& X^{T}AXX^{T} AX\\
& X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r},\\
& A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, \;\text{not necessarily symmetric}.\\\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\text{Define}, \;\;
f(X) &:= {\langle}X,AX{\rangle}_F =: g(X),\\
F(X) &\;= {\langle}X,AX{\rangle}_F^2 = f(X)g(X).\\\\
\partial_{X_{ij}}F(X)&=\partial_{X_{ij}}\{f(X)g(X)\}\\
&=\partial_{X_{ij}}\{f(X)\}g(X)+\partial_{X_{ij}}\{g(X)\}f(X)\\
&=2\partial_{X_{ij}}\{f(X)\}f(X)\;\; \because f(X)=g(X).\\\\
& \nabla_{X}f(X)=\nabla_{X}\langle X,AX\rangle=(A+A^T)X\\
\Rightarrow& \partial_{X_{ij}}\{f(X)\}=\Big[\;(A+A^T)X\;\Big]_{ij}\\\\
\therefore \nabla_{X_{}}\{F(X)\} &= 2\langle X,AX \rangle_F \; (A+A^T)X
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

==================================================================

## Matlab Script: Using Manifold Optimization Toolbox, manopt

result must be...

The slope should be 2. It appears to be: 2.00001.
If it is far from 2, then directional derivatives might be erroneous.
The residual should be 0, or very close. Residual: 0.
If it is far from 0, then the gradient is not in the tangent space.

==================================================================

clc;
close all;
clear;

addpath(genpath('C:\MatlabToolkits\YALMIP'));

dim_ = randi([1e1,1e2]);

n = dim_;
r = floor(dim_./2);
A = random('normal', 0, 1, n, n);   % A-Asymmetric

problem1        = [];
problem1.M      = euclideanfactory(n, r);
problem1.cost   = @(X) power((trace(X'*A*X)),2);
problem1.grad   = @(X) 2*trace(X'*A*X)*(A+A')*X;

pltcfg.decay = 0.75;
fprintf('========================================================== @k\n')
figure('Position', [0, 0, 1920*pltcfg.decay, 1080*pltcfg.decay]); 
checkgradient(problem1);
fprintf('\n\n');

Answer (score 0):

**NB:**   If $A$ is not symmetric, then replace it with $\Big(\tfrac{A+A^T}{2}\Big)$ in the following.

Define the scalar
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= x^TAx \cr
d\phi &= (2Ax)^Tdx \cr
}$$
Write the function in terms of this new variable. Then find its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
f &= \phi^2 \cr
df &= 2\phi\,d\phi = (4\phi Ax)^Tdx \cr
g = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= 4\phi Ax \cr\cr
}$$
Now find the differential of the gradient, and thence the hessian.
$$\eqalign{
dg &= 4\phi A\,dx + 4Ax\,d\phi \cr
   &= 4\phi A\,dx + (4Ax)(2Ax)^Tdx \cr
H=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} &= 4\phi A + 8Axx^TA \cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot Greg. my study is already working lovely empirically, but these completeness will be necessarily revisited when I write.